# Bootstrap 4 grid system layout not working on Safari

Tags: safari, bootstrap-4, grid-system

Just open this link with Firefox or other, and then with Safari.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex&stacked=h

code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Three equal width columns! Try to add a new div with class="col" inside the row class - this will create four equal-width columns.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="background-color:lavender;">.col</div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color:orange;">.col</div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color:lavender;">.col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What happens is that on safari the 3 cols appear under eachother and on other browsers they appear corretly in a same line block.

How can I fix Safari problem?

Comment: Hi Domingos, where you able to fix this problem? Thanks and kind regards, Gert.

Comment: Working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234112/7186739